# Spark to process many tar.gz files from s3

Tags: amazon-s3, apache-spark

I have many files in the format log-.tar.gz in s3. I would like to process them, process them (extract a field from each line) and store it in a new file.

There are many ways we can do this. One simple and convenient method is to access the files using textFile method.

```
//Read file from s3
rdd = sc.textFile("s3://bucket/project_name/date_folder/logfile1.*.gz")
```

I am concerned about the memory limit of the cluster. This way, the master node will be overloaded. Is there any rough estimate for the size of the files that can be processed by the type of clusters?

I am wondering if there is a way to parallelize the process of getting the *.gz files from s3 as they are already grouped by date.

Comment: It is already parallelized...

Comment: @zero323 Thanks for the answer. Do you mean the textFile method is the optimized way?

Comment: Yes, it is. That is why data has to accessible from all the worker nodes.

Answer (score 2):

With an exception of `parallelize` / `makeRDD` all methods creating `RDDs` / `DataFrames` require data to be accessible from all workers and are executed in parallel without loading on a driver.

Comment: Thanks for the answer. May I know if there is any rough estimate for the size of the files that can be processed

Comment: that depends on your query & cluster size as well